# SQLBuilder and Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Can anyone explain what is going on here.

I am generating a connection string for Entity Framework (codeFirst) to connect to a DB.  The two commented out line work fine, but using an SQL Builder fails with:

> Cannot open database "Church Accounts" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'JOHN-OFFICEPC\John'.

```
  //ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"data source="+Environment.MachineName + @"\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ChurchAccounts;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

  ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

  //ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"data source=JOHN-OFFICEPC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ChurchAccounts;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

  ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
```

The SQLBuilder string looks identical:

```
Data Source=JOHN-OFFICEPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="Church Accounts";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework
```

It would be much nicer and more flexible to use the SQLBuilder, but WHY won't it work.

Comment: There is a space in your database name in the SQL Builder which is different than your other connection strings that have no space:  "ChurchAccounts"

Comment: Isn't it amazing how you can look at code for ages and not spot the obvious!!!